# Why query takes time if table have no records

Tags: oracle, performance

We have deleted the all records of the table and after that we execute the select * from that table. Why this query takes time..?

Answer (score 6):

If you are planning deleting all records in your table, "TRUNCATE" might be an alternative. Just remember that truncate will do an implicit commit (A DDL command).

**The High Watermark Syndrome (HWM)**

You are experiencing the "HWM syndrome". If you insert one million rows into a table and do a `select count(*) from table`. Thereafter you delete all rows. When you now do a new `select count(*) from table`, it takes just as long time as with a million rows in it. What!! How is this possible??

*"Hey, there is nothing in there - and it takes forever. This database is terrible, Oracle isn't performing, MariaDB is so much better!"* (The HWM syndrome)

As always it boils down to understanding how the Oracle machinery is working.
No blocks are deleted when doing `delete from table`. They are saved for future inserts and updates. When doing a full table scan (no index scan) all blocks will will be read from the beginning until HWM. A truncate operation will reset the HWM.

You can read more about HWM [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:492636200346818072)

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

do select in ALL_TABLES and check the row_count , if it is not 0 then looks like stats are not updated. If not 0 then run

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('Schema_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME');
SELECT * from all_Tables where table_name = 'table_name'
then run the select statment
```